# React - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: reactjs

[image]
At first and according to Glide.js doc you just need to add this:

```
new Glide('.glide').mount();
```

However that throws the same error above until I used it like so:

```
import React from 'react';

import './Tiers.css';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  new Glide('.glide', {
    gap: 50,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    // focusAt: 1,
    peek: 200,
    perView: 3,
    type: 'carousel',
    breakpoints: {
      1600: {
        perView: 2,
      },
      1100: {
        perView: 1,
        peek: 80,
      },
    },
  }).mount();
});
```

That works on the homepage, but on other pages it gives that error.

The script tag is in the index.html in the head.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution; the solution is to wrap the entire code into UseEffect().

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import './Tiers.css';

const Tiers = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      new Glide('.glide', {
        gap: 50,
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        // focusAt: 1,
        peek: 200,
        perView: 3,
        type: 'carousel',
        breakpoints: {
          1600: {
            perView: 2,
          },
          1100: {
            perView: 1,
            peek: 80,
          },
        },
      }).mount();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="tiers" id="tiers">
      <h2 className="sectionTitle">Tiers</h2>

      <div className="glide">
        <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
          <div className="glide__slides">
            <div className="glide__slide tierBox">
              <h4>Tier One</h4>
              <span className="tierTitle">Description:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Cost:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Starting:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test 2:</span>
            </div>

            <div className="glide__slide tierBox">
              <h4>Tier One</h4>
              <span className="tierTitle">Description:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Cost:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Starting:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test 2:</span>
            </div>

            <div className="glide__slide tierBox">
              <h4>Tier One</h4>
              <span className="tierTitle">Description:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Cost:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Starting:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test 2:</span>
            </div>

            <div className="glide__slide tierBox">
              <h4>Tier One</h4>
              <span className="tierTitle">Description:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Cost:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Starting:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test 2:</span>
            </div>

            <div className="glide__slide tierBox">
              <h4>Tier One</h4>
              <span className="tierTitle">Description:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Cost:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Starting:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test:</span>

              <span className="tierTitle">Test 2:</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
          <button type="button" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">prev</button>
          <button type="button" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">next</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};
export default Tiers;
```